# I am getting this error "ErrorException Trying to access array offset on value of type null " in my browser when I am learning http client in laravel

Tags: laravel

here it is my usercontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function index(){
        $collection= Http::get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1");
        return view('users',['collection'=>$collection['data']]);
    }
}
```

and my composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3.1|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format and explain your problem. This is pretty unreadable and even if it was formatted correctly the question is still vague. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I edited and is still unreadable?

Comment: Yes and even if the question is formatted correctly, you are really not asking a question and not including the correct parts please read how to ask

Answer (score -1):

I assume you want to hit an API endpoint.Can you try to check if you return any status on the API call. Use this`$response = Http::get($url); $response->status()` to check for the response's status.If its working, you can then try to obtain the json of the response.